# Lisp unbound symbol

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am learning lisp and i am trying to create simple function to sum arr.

```
(defun sum( N )
    ( if ( null N )
         nil
         ( + (car N ) ( sum ( cdr N )))))

(sum '(1 2 3 ))
```

yet it throws error

> Error: execute: unbound symbol: "N" []

The parenthesis should be correct. Why is this throwing the error or what is wrong with logic behind my code?

If list is empty it will return nil , if not , it will return first element + rest of the list recursively.

Thanks for help

Comment: Voting to close this as the error message seem to orginate from a bad interpreter and not directly related to the code.  I also don't think this question and the supplied answer can help future SOUs

Comment: Even if the problem is due to a "bad" interpreter, others are likely to encounter that same interpreter too. Wouldn't they find this question helpful?

Comment: *"If list is empty it will return nil , if not , it will return first element +* **the sum of the** *rest of the list recursively."* Always try simple cases, to see what's going on. `() --> NIL`; `(1) --> 1 + sum() = 1 + NIL`.

Answer (score 9):

The base case is incorrect, you're *adding* the numbers in a list, hence you can't return `nil`, it'll fail when you try to add a number to it. Try this:

```
(defun sum (N)
  (if (null N)
      0
      (+ (car N) (sum (cdr N)))))
```

Comment: @Johnyb this works for me: `(sum '(1 2 3))` ... are you sure you're not passing a variable called `N`, which was not defined before?

Comment: No, i fixed the error thanks. I was using some online interpreter that was throwing erros , tried it on linux and it worked.